# GWT editor frame work is not working

Tags: gwt

I have  a bean named SignUpBean and it's editor is SignUpBeanEditor and following is its Driver interface.

```
public interface SignUpDriver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<SignUpBean, SignUpEditor>{

}
```

Following is entry point class

```
public class Signup implements EntryPoint {
private SignUpDriver signUpDriver;
private SignUpEditor signUpEditor;
private SignUpBean signUpBean;
private VerticalPanel verticalPanel;
private Label signUpLbl;
private Button submitButton;
private Button cancelButton;
private RequestBuilder requestBuilder;
final SignUpConverter signUpConverter=GWT.create(SignUpConverter.class);
public void onModuleLoad() {
    signUpLbl = new Label("Sign Up");
    signUpDriver = GWT.create(SignUpDriver.class);

    signUpBean = new SignUpBean();
    signUpEditor = new SignUpEditor();
    submitButton = new Button("Submit");
    cancelButton = new Button("Cancel");
    signUpDriver.initialize(signUpEditor);





signUpDriver.edit(signUpBean);

    System.out.println(signUpBean.getUserName());

    submitButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        SignUpBean  signUpBeanEdited=signUpDriver.flush();
}
}
}
}
```

I am getting only null value from `signUpBeanEdited` after giving value in UI. If i am initializing `SignUpBean` with constructor then also data is not binding to UI. My problem is I cant bind data in GWT UI using editor framework.

Comment: Please list the `SignUpEditor` and `SignUpBean` - what you have so far seems to make sense, but those classes are needed for more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields( sub editors ) declared in **SignUpEditor** should be of at least **DEFAULT** scope. I guess you declared them as private. If so, the Editor Impl classes generated cannot access the fields to bind the data.

Changing scope to  at least **DEFAULT** might solve your problem.